# trigger.io java.lang.NullPointerException in android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl crash report

Tags: android, android-webview, trigger.io

I've received some crash reports from Google Play for an Android app created with Trigger.io.

How can I track down what is happening here? This is the report I'm receiving:

java.lang.NullPointerException
in android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:1900)
at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(WebView.java:1912)
at io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity$4.run(ForgeActivity.java:442)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how about posting a little of this o.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity$4.run(ForgeActivity.java:442) ?

Comment: Thanks. As trigger.io is a 3rd party html-native app wrapper service unfortunately I don't have access to that class source. This is the best I can find: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/_static/native/android/reference/io/trigger/forge/android/core/ForgeActivity.html

Comment: An official answer from Trigger.IO would be useful here.

Comment: Sorry, can't add too much more here without knowing stuff like the Android version and Trigger.io platform version this install was built from...

Comment: Forge 1.4.24, unfortunately Google play doesn't give the API or device version for ANRs / crashes so I don't know that info.